# Appium with ChromeDriver to web view application

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Appium but I have experience with selenium.
I need to write tests for a web view app.
But when I need to find an element I need to use the `UIAutomatorViewer` and use it like it's a native app.
Is there a way to use the DOM to navigate like when I'm working with the Chrome browser?
I tried this:

```
AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver;
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "LG - SERVER SERVER's Orange - G3");
cap.SetCapability("apppackage", "com.essence.adlfamily");
driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```